# Find a linear map $T : \Bbb R^3 → \Bbb R^4$ whose image is generated by $\{(1, 2, 0, 4),(2, 0, −1, −3)\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear map
$$T: \mathbb R^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb R^4$$
whose image is generated by $\{(1,2,0,4), (2,0,-1,-3)\}$.

I amm not sure if my question is worded very well, but I'm having trouble understanding how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Map $(1,0,0)$ to $(1, 2, 0, 4),$ and map both $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ to $(2, 0, −1, −3).$ As a linear map is described by its values on a basis, you're done.